# How can I wait for an axios post request to be executed inside another axios interceptors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have axioss interceptors:

```
instance.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
      const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
      const auth = jwt_decode(accessToken);
      const expireTime = auth.exp * 1000;
      const now = + new Date();
      if (expireTime > now) {
        config.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
      } else {
        (async() => {
          const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");
          const response = await refreshAccessToken(refreshToken);
          const data = response.data;
          console.log(data);
          const accessToken = data.accessToken;
          setAuth({token: accessToken,refreshToken});
          localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
          localStorage.setItem("access_token", accessToken);
          config.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
          console.log("refresh is finished")
        })();        
      }
      console.log("exist from interceptors")
      return config;
    },
    (error) => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
```

*refresh token function*

```
const refreshAccessToken = (token) => {
    return refreshInstance.post("/refresh", token);
};
```

I tried in different ways.If i do so:

```
(async() => {
          const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");
          const response = await refreshAccessToken(refreshToken);
          const data = response.data;
          console.log(data);
          const accessToken = data.accessToken;
          setAuth({token: accessToken,refreshToken});
          localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
          localStorage.setItem("access_token", accessToken);
          config.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
          console.log("refresh is finished")
        })();
```

The way I think because of async, the function exits before the update and the page needs to be reloaded again.

If i remove async and leave just the body , then nothing changes .The function exits before the token is updated.

i also tried:

```
else {
    ...
    const response = await refreshAccessToken(refreshToken);
}
```

with :

```
const refreshAccessToken = async (token) => {
    return instance.post("/refresh", token);
};
```

But then it gives an error: `Unexpected reserved word 'await'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide async callback to `interceptors.use`, no need for IIFE .Something like this:

```
instance.interceptors.request.use(
async (config) => {
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
  const auth = jwt_decode(accessToken);
  const expireTime = auth.exp * 1000;
  const now = + new Date();
  if (expireTime > now) {
    config.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
  } else {
      const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");
      const response = await refreshAccessToken(refreshToken);
      const data = response.data;
      console.log(data);
      const accessToken = data.accessToken;
      setAuth({token: accessToken,refreshToken});
      localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
      localStorage.setItem("access_token", accessToken);
      config.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
      console.log("refresh is finished")
  }
  console.log("exist from interceptors")
  return config;
},
(error) => {
  return Promise.reject(error);
}
```

);

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot.However, I didn't really understand why async for request made the request wait.

Comment: Key point is that inside your `interceptors.use` you need to wait for something(in your case to get new token), and when you want to wait for something inside a function, you must make that function async, otherwise it will be executed synchronously no matter what you write inside the body. In your solution you created IIFEE but the problem is that you were not waiting IFEE to finish it's execution - you called IIFEE synchronously(no await), and code immediately ended. So in order to wait you need await, and since you need await then you need to make callback async.